# Rotating Galton board

Tags: pr.probability

What kind of distribution would one get by rotating a Galton board with constant angular velocity?

[image: Rotating Galton board]

Comment: Using the setup in the image, where the buckets are all in one line that rotates with the pegs, I think the final distribution is unaffected by the rotation.

Comment: Ok, so you mean around a vertical axis in the picture, right? At first I thought around a horizontal axis going inside the pic. That would be devilish to figure out, I guess.

Comment: @MattF., the distribution is pretty much decided just before the buckets are reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the presence of rotation, the original diffusion process is biased by the centrifugal "force", corresponding to a *repulsive* harmonic potential. Diffusion in a one-dimensional harmonic potential is solved, for example, [here](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS498/LectureNotes/chp4.pdf). Although the discussion there implicitly assumes a positive spring constant $f$, corresponding to an attractive harmonic potential, I have checked that the given solution also applies at negative $f$, corresponding to the repulsive case. In short, the distribution continues to be Gaussian, but with an increased width compared to the non-rotating board.

Comment: This seems like the right answer. There is a radial outward drift. But it could be more complicated than that. To really consider the details, such as whether one is trying to affect the velocity or the acceleration with the noise, seems like a science problem, not math. Probably physics.

Comment: @ShannonStarr - Certainly, describing a physical system mathematically requires the adoption of a model, in which one strives to retain only the physical effects relevant to the desired accuracy, while discarding all others. Formulating the model is a question of physics, not mathematics. Here, the most obvious model assumption being made is the continuum limit, but there are numerous others, such as the effects of friction at the level of individual bounces.

Comment: The model here is that, before introducing rotation, the system carries out a simple one-dimensional random walk, which in the continuum limit can be shown to result in the standard diffusion equation. The individual trajectories constituting the ensemble are governed by Newton's second law, and introducing rotation adds the centrifugal term to Newton's law, acting as an external deterministic force. How such a force modifies diffusion is discussed in detail in the given reference.

Comment: There is the question as to the source of randomness, the model of the scattering. Depending on the context, that moves the problem to the level of statistical mechanics or condensed-matter/stat-mech if that is what one is really interested in. In a plinko type set-up, the friction of the pegs is the real issue, exactly as you say. If the angular velocity were rapid enough, then probably the ball would just keep bouncing up until it reached the edges of the box.

Comment: As an example of how engineering or physics enters the discussion I refer to https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/dyn_coin_07.pdf They were considering coin tossing, not Plinko. But I think there is something related here. If the Plinko game is too small for a simplified model of scattering to be valid, then the problem is a complicated science question.

Comment: Whatever model you adopt, it will only describe a real Galton board up to a certain accuracy - there is no exact mathematical description, regardless of how elaborately you model. You pick an accuracy, and you refine your model up to the point where your accuracy requirements are satisfied. There are correlations between simultaneously falling balls induced by the sound waves they emit, the echoing of which depends on the shape of the chamber and the filling gas.